# Swift: make custom progress view follow user tap? UIBezier

Tags: swift, swift3, uiview, path, uiprogressview

Ok I have a custom UIProgressView in shape of a circle implemented here:

```
class PlaybackLineView: UIView {
    var percentage: Float = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            if percentage > 1 {
                //print("happned!")
                percentage = 1.0
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.setNeedsDisplay()
            }
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let playbackRed = UIColor(red: 181/255.0, green: 23/255.0, blue: 65/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        playbackRed.setFill()
        playbackRed.setStroke()

        let newWidth = rect.size.width * CGFloat(percentage)
        let fillRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: rect.size.height)
        let fillRectPath = UIBezierPath(rect: fillRect)
        fillRectPath.fill()
    }

@IBInspectable public var drawEndPoint: Bool = true
    @IBInspectable public var drawWhenZero: Bool = false
    @IBInspectable public var strokeWidth: CGFloat = 3.0

    let smallCircleRadius: CGFloat = 6.0
    var fullCirclePath: UIBezierPath!


    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if !drawWhenZero && (percentage == 0 || percentage == 1) { return }

        UIColor.clear.setFill()

        let arcCenter = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
        let radius = (rect.width - smallCircleRadius * 2) / 2.0

        let circleGray = UIColor(red: 218/255.0, green: 218/255.0, blue: 218/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        circleGray.setStroke()
        fullCirclePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle:CGFloat.pi * 2, clockwise: true)
        fullCirclePath.lineWidth = strokeWidth
        fullCirclePath.fill()
        fullCirclePath.stroke()

        let circleRed = UIColor(red: 181/255.0, green: 23/255.0, blue: 65/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        circleRed.setStroke()
        let arcPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle:CGFloat.pi * 2 * CGFloat(percentage), clockwise: true)
        arcPath.fill()
        arcPath.stroke()
        arcPath.lineWidth = strokeWidth

        if !drawEndPoint { return }

        let smallCirclePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcPath.currentPoint, radius: smallCircleRadius, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle:CGFloat.pi * 2, clockwise: true)
        circleRed.setFill()
        smallCirclePath.fill()
        smallCirclePath.stroke()

        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (-90).degreesToRadians)
    }
```

This moves the small circle along the path of the larger circle according to `percentage`. Issue is I need to allow the user to control this percentage by tapping/scrubbing ON the UIBezierPath -

So far Ive gotten this that gets whether the tap was within the larger circle:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
            // do something with your currentPoint

            if(fullCirclePath.contains(currentPoint))
            {
                print("CONTAINS!: ", currentPoint)
                //percentage = 0.5
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I get how much (in percentage) of the larger circle the tap is along the path, from this CGPoint?

What Ive tried:

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        // do something with your currentPoint

```
    //print(fullCirclePath.cgPath.cen)
    if(fullCirclePath.contains(currentPoint))
    {

        touchAngle = atan2((currentPoint.x-arcCenter.x), (currentPoint.y-arcCenter.y))
        percentage = Float(touchAngle * 100)/Float(M_PI * 2)
        print("CONTAINS!: ", currentPoint, "Angle: ", touchAngle.radiansToDegrees, " Percent: ", percentage)

        if(AudioPlayerManager.shared.isPlaying())
        {
            AudioPlayerManager.shared.seek(toProgress: percentage)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold tight this involves some math!

Assuming the centre of your circle is (0, 0). Say you have a point (x, y) lying on the circumference, you can use the [atan2 or arctan2 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) to get the angle (in radians; *radians being what you want as `UIBezierPath` uses radians*) the point lies with respect to the centre of the circle. So, with this angle, you know where on the circumference of your circle the user has touched (call it `touch angle`). You can use this as your `endAngle` on `UIBezierPath`.

**Note:** If your circle's centre is not (0, 0) but is (x1, y1), compensate by subtracting the difference from the touch points (x, y) i.e, your new points are (x - x1, y - y1)

[image: Angles in the default coordinate system]

If you want a percentage of how much of the circumference the point covers from 0 rads. You can use the formula `percentage = (touch angle*(in rads)* * 100)/2π)`.

> **More on atan2/arctan2**

You can calculate your touch angle using the formula `touch angle = tan^(-1)(y/x)` aka `touch angle = arctan2(y,x)`. Where **(x, y)** are the points the user has touched on the circumference.

> **Example and explanation** (Edit)

Okay *phew*, after some research, I figured it out.
Take a [look at this code](http://CircularSlider/CircularSlider/Classes/UICircularSliderView.swift), notice the `touchesBegan(_ ...` function.

```
public override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    for touch in touches {
        let point = touch.location(in: self)
        if backCircleBezierPath!.contains(point) {
            print("contains")
            let centeredPoint = CGPoint(x: (point.x - frame.width/2), y: (point.y - frame.height/2))
            print(centeredPoint)
            var rads = atan(centeredPoint.y/centeredPoint.x)
            if centeredPoint.x < 0 {
                rads += CGFloat.pi
            } else if centeredPoint.x > 0 && centeredPoint.y < 0 {
                rads += CGFloat.pi * 2
            }
            let perc = (rads - backCircleStartAngle) / abs(backCircleStartAngle - backCircleEndAngle)
            frontCircleShapeLayer?.strokeEnd = perc
        }
    }
}
```

I've used `CAShapeLayer` instead of drawing in `draw(_ rect...`; I recommend you do that same. Your way works fine too but with a few changes which I will mention in the end.

I've used two arcs: 
1. Placeholder arc - `backCircleShapeLayer`
2. Progress indicator arc - `frontCircleShapeLayer`

When the user taps on the placeholder arc, we can calculate the angle (in radians) and draw the progress indicator arc from `start Angle` to `touch Angle` as mentioned before (*use this method for drawing strokes directly with `UIBezierPath` in the `draw(_ ...` method*), but what I'm doing is using those values to calculate the fraction `perc` (between 0 and 1) and using that as the `stroke end` of the progress arc.

This brings to some interesting new learning. The value of `atan(y/x)` is domain specific ([Some math behind this, if you're interested](https://www.mathsisfun.com/polar-cartesian-coordinates.html)). So **if your touch is in the 4th quadrant you add 360˚ or 2π and if it is in the 2nd or 3rd quadrant you add 180˚ or π**. After this addition your `touch angle` should reflect the perfect value.

Comment: Thanks! Im having some math difficulty here - not working. I posted what I did in edit - tried subtracting my path center but getting weird angles

Comment: Updated the answer with more math and a GitHub link :) The code half-ass works right now, just keep the frame of the view a square and the `minAngle` less than the `maxAngle`

Comment: Sorry, still not getting this. The GitHub link didn't work but regardless I don't know how to properly get backCircleStartAngle or backCircleEndAngle. Can you post an implementation in line with my code?

Comment: You can download that project from GitHub and run it, it has an implementation in the example folder or something like that